# How to detect if option provided via \tikzset

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I would like to be able to detect if a particular option has been provided via a `\tikzset` and issue a message based on that.

The MWE yields:

[image]

But once the conditional works (just a comment for now) it should yield:

[image]

### Notes:

- Even though I don't think that this case introduces any additional complexity,
  I am not concerned about the case where a `\tikzset` uses a style defined by another `\tikzset`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{Hollow/.style={red}}
\tikzset{Solid/.style={green}}

\newcommand{\TikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [ultra thick, blue, ->, My Options] (0,0) -- (1,0)
        % If option Hollow is specified
            node [right] {Error: Option Hollow specified.}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tikzset{My Options/.style={Hollow}}
\TikzPicture

\tikzset{My Options/.style={}}
\TikzPicture
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hollow is defined as a style so it's a combination of certain key=value pairs, it doesn't set a distinctive switch per se when called. If it's a distinct option you can `/.try` it at the first instance then it's gonna stay there.

Comment: @percusse: Never heard of `/.try`, will have to look that up..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit:** Via the `.forward to` handler (only available with the CVS version of PGF) , you can attach a boolean to your `Hollow` style when you want to test if it is specified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{Hollow}

\tikzset{
  Hollow is used/.code=\booltrue{Hollow},
  Test Hollow/.code={\tikzset{Hollow/.forward to=/tikz/Hollow is used}},
  Hollow/.style={red},
  Solid/.style={green},
}

\newcommand{\TikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [Test Hollow,ultra thick, blue, ->, My Options] (0,0) -- (1,0)
        \ifbool{Hollow}{
          node [right] {Error: Option Hollow specified.}
        }{
          node [right] {Ok: Option Hollow is not specified.}
        }
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tikzset{My Options/.style={Hollow}}
\TikzPicture

\tikzset{My Options/.style={}}
\TikzPicture

\tikzset{Hollow/.style={violet,dotted}}

\tikzset{My Options/.style={Hollow}}
\TikzPicture

\end{document}
```

[image]

**First solution** (with version 2.10 of PGF):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{Hollow}

\tikzset{
  Hollow/.code={
    \booltrue{Hollow}
    \pgfkeysalso{red}
  },
  Solid/.style={green},
}

\newcommand{\TikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [ultra thick, blue, ->, My Options] (0,0) -- (1,0)
        \ifbool{Hollow}{node [right] {Error: Option Hollow specified.}}{}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\tikzset{My Options/.style={Hollow}}
\TikzPicture

\tikzset{My Options/.style={}}
\TikzPicture

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for your comment. I pushed your idea a little further...

Comment: You don't need etoolbox for booleans. You can add an `/.is if` to hollow and it would be set in a similar fashion.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes! Though, the `/.forward to` handler is only available with the CVS version of PGF, isn’t it?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Oops! You are right! I always forget to check whether what I propose is already available in version 2.10 of PGF.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Well, the definition of `.forward to` is four lines of code long. I think one could insert that in their source.

Answer (score 3):

This approach re-defined the `.style` handler by appending (in this case)

```
\expandafter\let\csname ifqrr@trace@pgfk@/tikz/Hollow\endcsname\iftrue
```

to it. Now, `/tikz/Hollow` is stored in the macro `\pgfkeyscurrentpath`, so we need to expand it once, because, of course, `\pgfkeyscurrentpath` will be different when the style is called.

This is the reason I used `.ecode` instead of `.code` for the redefinition of the `.style` handler:

```
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.style/.code=
    \pgfkeys{
      \pgfkeyscurrentpath/.ecode=
        \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\let\noexpand
             \csname ifqrr@trace@pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath\noexpand\endcsname\noexpand\iftrue
        \noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    }
}
```

This has the following consequences:

- Currently, it only works with `.style`, not with `.estyle`, `.style args`, `.estyle args`, `.style 2 args` or `.style n args`. It also does not work with the handler `.append style` (which is often used) with a previous undefined style, i.e. `.append style` without a previous `.style`.
- It does not work with previous defined styles.

I also have defined a two-argument expecting `.if` handler that tests if the key is given, but sadly, it cannot be used inside a path. Therefore I have defined a very simple `\iftikzstyle` macro that only works for keys in the `/tikz/` path but it can be used inside a path.

#### Further Improvements

- Re-defining all other `style` handlers (its just expansion `;)`)
- We need to go deeper:

  It would be better to add the `\let` sequence where the styles are called if one specifies it (for example with `\tikzset` or in the optional arguments of a `\draw`). This could make existing/pre-defined styles also available for `/.if` and `\iftikzstyle`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.style/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.ecode=\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\let\noexpand\csname ifqrr@trace@pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath\noexpand\endcsname\noexpand\iftrue\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\unexpanded{#1}}}}
\pgfkeys{
    /handlers/.if/.code 2 args={% works not in the middle of a path
        \expandafter\ifx\csname ifqrr@trace@pgfk@\pgfkeyscurrentpath\endcsname\iftrue#1\else#2\fi}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\iftikzstyle}[1]{% only for /tikz/ styles
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ifqrr@trace@pgfk@/tikz/#1\endcsname\iftrue
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{Hollow/.style={red}}
\tikzset{Solid/.style={green}}

\newcommand{\TikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [ultra thick, blue, ->, My Options] (0,0) -- (1,0)
          \iftikzstyle{Hollow}{node[right] {Error: Option Hollow specified.}}{node[opacity=.5,right] {Option Hollow not specified}}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
\tikzset{My Options/.style={Hollow}}
\TikzPicture

\tikzset{My Options/.style={}}
\TikzPicture

\tikzset{Hollow/.if={Hollow is specified.}{Hollow is not specified.}}

\tikzset{Hollow}
\tikzset{Hollow/.if={Hollow is specified.}{Hollow is not specified.}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]