# Difference between \newbool and \newtoggle from etoolbox package

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

Paul Gaborit's answer to [How to detect if option provided via \tikzset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101072/4301) uses

- `\newbool` to define a new boolean
- `\booltrue` to set a boolean, and
- `\ifbool` to perform a conditional operation

all from [the `etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox).
Well, I have been using

- `\newtoggle` to define a new toggle
- `\toggletrue` to set a toggle, and
- `\iftoggle` to perform a conditional operation

also from the same package.

Is there a difference between the two? Is one preferable over the other?

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{ToggleCondition}
\newbool{BooleanCondition}

\newcommand*{\CheckBoolean}{\ifbool{BooleanCondition}{true}{false}}
\newcommand*{\CheckToggle}{\iftoggle{ToggleCondition}{true}{false}}

\begin{document}

\toggletrue{ToggleCondition}
ToggleCondition is \CheckToggle.

\togglefalse{ToggleCondition}
ToggleCondition is \CheckToggle.

\medskip
\booltrue{BooleanCondition}
BooleanCondition is now \CheckBoolean.

\boolfalse{BooleanCondition}
BooleanCondition is now \CheckBoolean.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\newbool{mybool}` is almost the same as `\newif`, *but* it checks whether `\ifmybool` is already defined, which LaTeX doesn't:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\newbool}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname if#1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\newif\csname if#1\endcsname}}
```

There's also `\providebool` which does nothing if the conditional is already defined.

Similarly, `\ifbool` is a wrapper around the usual construction

```
\if...
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
```

with a preliminary check whether the conditional is defined. So it can be used also for primitive conditionals:

```
\ifbool{hmode}{<something for horizontal mode>}{<something else>}
```

Instead `\newtoggle{mytoggle}` is defined by

```
\newrobustcmd*{\newtoggle}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}
    {\etb@error{Toggle '#1' already defined}\@eha}
    {\cslet{etb@tgl@#1}\@secondoftwo}}
```

so it checks whether the toggle is already defined and, if not, it sets it to "false". The constructed macro `\etb@tgl@mytoggle` is either `\@firstoftwo` (corresponding to "true") or `\@secondoftwo` (corresponding to "false"). When one says

```
\iftoggle{mytoggle}{<true>}{<false>}
```

`etoolbox` simply checks whether the toggle is defined and, if it is, just puts `\etb@tgl@mytoggle` in the input stream, thus doing "the right thing", because it chooses either `<true>` or `<false>` depending if it is `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo`.

Note that `\toggletrue` is defined as

```
\newrobustcmd*{\toggletrue}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}
    {\cslet{etb@tgl@#1}\etb@toggletrue}
    {\etb@noglobal\etb@err@notoggle{#1}}}
```

so it can be preceded by `\global`: indeed `\ifcsdef` is expandable, so if the toggle `foo` is not defined, after `\global\toggletrue{foo}` we'd remain with

```
\global\etb@noglobal\etb@err@notoggle{#1}}
```

which becomes

```
\global\let\relax\relax\etb@err@notoggle{#1}
```

that effectively removes the `\global` by doing a harmless `\let` (almost harmless, because it can impact on the stack memory, but since there's an error raised anyway, the user will correct it). If instead the toggle `\foo` is defined, we remain with

```
\global\cslet{etb@tgl@foo}\etb@toggletrue
```

so, again,

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname etb@tgl@foo\endcsname\etb@toggletrue
```

where `\etb@toggletrue` is the same as `\@firstoftwo`. The same holds, of course, for `\togglefalse`.

Which one to prefer? If you plan to use also the traditional `\if...` syntax, then `\newbool` is needed. Otherwise it's just a matter of personal preference.

Both booleans and toggles can be used in boolean expression (`\ifboolexpr`), so there's no difference for that usage either. Note that `\global\booltrue` and `\global\boolfalse` are legal too.

Answer (score 24):

The answer to this is specified in the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) under section **3.5 Boolean Flags** (p 12 onward):

> **3.5.1 TeX Flags**
>   Since the tools in this section are based on `\newif` internally, they may be used
>   to test and alter the state of ﬂags previously deﬁned with `\newif`. They are also
>   compatible with the boolean tests of the `ifthen` package and may serve as a LaTeX
>   interface for querying TeX primitives such as `\ifmmode`. The `\newif` approach requires a total of three macros per ﬂag.

This means that using `\newbool{cs}` is similar to `\newif\ifcs` which creates 3 macros: `\ifcs`, `\cstrue` and `\csfalse`.

> **3.5.2 LaTeX Flags**
>   In contrast to the ﬂags from section 3.5.1, the tools in this section require only one
>   macro per ﬂag. They also use a separate namespace to avoid name clashes with
>   regular macros.

This uses a single macro for each flag. The reference to "namespace" implies that you can use

```
\newbool{mybool}
\newtoggle{mybool}
```

without running into problems.

Preference? User-specific, in my opinion. Back in the 80's, when memory availability was a concern, perhaps `\newtoggle` would have been preferred... but we live in the present, which doesn't have that restriction.

---

Some technical details from [`etoolbox.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty):

- `\newbool` is equivalent to `\newif`, apart from making sure that the condition can be defined via `\@ifdefinable`:

  ```
  \newrobustcmd*{\newbool}[1]{%
    \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname if#1\endcsname{%
      \expandafter\newif\csname if#1\endcsname}}
  ```
- `\newtoggle{cs}` creates `\etb@tgl@cs`:

  ```
  \newrobustcmd*{\newtoggle}[1]{%
    \ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}
      {\etb@error{Toggle '#1' already defined}\@eha}
      {\cslet{etb@tgl@#1}\@secondoftwo}}
  ```

Comment: So basically, "no difference". :-)