# \iftoggledefined: Detect if newtoggle was defined

Tags: macros, conditionals, etoolbox

I am looking for `\iftoggledefined{<toggle name>}{<true>}{<false>}`. I checked the `etoolbox` documentation and did not see such a thing.

Based on [Difference between \newbool and \newtoggle from etoolbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101083/4301), one could use `\ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}`, but if the etoolbox code was ever change this test would break.  Thus, would prefer to use an offical macro if it exists.

#### Question:

Can I obtain the same output as the given MWE

> ToggleA: Exists
>
> ToggleB: Does Not Exist

*without* relying on the internal `etb@tgl@#1` code of `etoolbox`.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iftoggledefined}[3]{\ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\newtoggle{ToggleA}

\begin{document}
ToggleA: \iftoggledefined{ToggleA}{Exists}{Does Not Exist}

ToggleB: \iftoggledefined{ToggleB}{Exists}{Does Not Exist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `\newtoggle` uses `\ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}`, I guess that this is a safe test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\newtoggle` checks `\ifcsdef{etb@tgl@#1}`, I believe this is a safe test.

There's no code in the package to check for a toggle to be defined (it's the same with `\newif` of the kernel or `\newboolean` of `ifthen`) and I'm not sure what it would be useful for.

Make a feature request, in the meantime use the code you proposed (and rethink to its usefulness).